# Trying to call a method in a method from another class

Tags: java

```
public void toonBoten()
    {
        for(Boot tweedeboot: boten)
        {
            Boot.toonBoot();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call the method toonBoot from the class Boot. This should be done for every tweedeboot of the type Boot (same as the class) from the ArrayList boten. toonBoot prints a few lines of information (basically it's a number of coordinates).

For some reason, I always receive the error "non-static method toonBoot() cannot be referenced from a static context".
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: how did you call the current method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call method on `instance`.

```
public void toonBoten()
    {
        for(Boot tweedeboot: boten)
        {
            tweedeboot.toonBoot();
        }
    }
```

Where

```
  Boot.toonBoot(); //means toonBoot() is a static method in Boot class
```

See:

- [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

**What you are doing**

By calling the method from the `Class name`, you're telling the compiler that this method is a `static` method. That is, calling `Boot.hello()` that the method signature for `hello()` is something like:

```
public static void hello() {}
```

**What you should do**

Call from the object reference, or in this case `tweedeboot`. This tells the compiler that the method is either a `static` method or an `instance` method, and it will check the instance as well as the class.